# Processing draw() method use not working

Tags: java, processing

I have code that changes the color and opacity of a PShape, I was debugging it and I'm 99% sure all the methods work. I made a delay method because Processing doesn't have a built-in delay method anymore. When I was debugging it I noticed that it would only draw what it was supposed to after all the delay calls where done (it would draw the latest version of the PShape when there was no more delays). So I looked at my delay method and I messed around with it but still no correct outcome. Can someone try to explain to me why PShape is not updating?

EDIT* I received an answer telling me to use noLoop(), I googled how to use it but I can't seem to find the correct place to put it. I've tried the very first line in the flash method, in setup (but then I realized I had live buttons that weren't updating)

The code below that makes a PShape's flash twice:

```
    noLoop();      
root.setVal(newVal);
root.highlight(0,255,0);
root.setopacity(200);
redraw();
try {Thread.sleep((long)1500);} 
catch (InterruptedException ex) {println("Error!");}
root.setopacity(0);
redraw();
try {Thread.sleep((long)1500);} 
catch (InterruptedException ex) {println("Error!");}
root.setopacity(200);
root.clearHL();//just to make sure I repeated these methods
root.highlight(0,255,0);
redraw();
try {Thread.sleep((long)1500);} 
catch (InterruptedException ex) {println("Error!");}
root.clearHL();
redraw();
loop();
return root;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to show more of your code (for example the `setup` function),
however your problem seems to stem from that fact that you may not have called `noLoop();` before trying to manually redraw objects.

This will cause the object to flash up for a frame before being overwritten by Processings automatic redraw.

As an aside, you can use a `Timer` for such things as delays if you so wish.

Or use `Sleep`:

```
import java.lang.Thread.*;

noLoop();
root.setVal(newVal);
root.highlight(0,255,0);
root.setopacity(200);
redraw();
Thread.sleep(1500);;
root.setopacity(0);
redraw();
Thread.sleep(1500);
root.setopacity(200);
root.clearHL();//just to make sure I repeated these methods
root.highlight(0,255,0);
redraw();
Thread.sleep(1500);
root.clearHL();
redraw();
```

Comment: So shall I just put noLoop(); right before all of the redraw() functions and the call loop() after they have ended?

Comment: @Runeony1 no, if you run `noloop` you should not run `loop` again unless you want to wipe all your custom draws.

Comment: ok, I put noLoop() at the first line of the method, no loop() or noLoop() call anywhere else... doesn't work

Comment: I've added a replacment for your delay method. See if that works for you.

Comment: I tried leaving and taking out the redraw() calls and nothing is still showing

Comment: I don't know what you are doing, if you make modifications to your code please post them in the question.

Comment: Sorry, never mind that, function sleep does not exist. Do I have to import something?

Comment: Unfortunatly I can't use chat due to work proxy, but yes you need to import `import java.lang.Thread.*;`

Comment: Ok, I got thread.sleep to work but it still doesn't update correctly

Comment: get rid of the `loop` at the very end, should be good after that.